# Composite JSONB array query in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Table: `test`, JSONB column: `content`:

```sql
create table test (id bigserial primary key, content jsonb);
```

`content` contains a list of fixed-length lists:

```sql
insert into test values (1, '[["first 1", "second 3"]]');
insert into test values (2, '[["first 1", "second 2"], ["first 2", "second 3"]]');
insert into test values (3, '[["first 1", "second 2"], ["first 1", "second 3"]]');
insert into test values (4, '[["first 2", "second 3"], ["first 1", "second 2"], ["first 1", "second 2"]]');
```

What's the correct Postgres syntax for a query that returns **all rows where
at least one of the `content` elements satisfies `(first element = "first 1")` AND `(second element ILIKE "%3%")`**?

That is, in the example above, it should select rows 1 and 3, but not 2 or 4.

*Bonus question*: what is the **most efficient** way to do such query (in case there are multiple alternatives)? Does it make sense to look into GIN over JSONB with `pg_trgm`? (There are millions of rows, the inner string values are typically 10-100 characters long, and each `content` list contains 0-1000s of lists (most usually 0).)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inner select expands array elements into separate rows with jsonb_array_elements, outer select does the filtering you want. See [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/1faf8/32) for live example.

```
select * from (
select id, jsonb_array_elements(content) as item from test  
) as expandedtest
where item->>0 like 'first 1' and item->>1 like '%3%'
```

Answer (score 3):

You should split apart the top level arrays and check the elements from there:

```
select distinct id, content
FROM test
JOIN lateral (
    select elems 
    FROM jsonb_array_elements(content) jae(elems)
) all_arrays ON TRUE
WHERE elems ->> 0 = 'first 1'
and elems ->> 1 ilike '%3%'
ORDER BY 1;
```

As for the best way to do this, that depends a lot on your actual data - how many rows, how big these jsonb structures are, etc.  In general, though, a search like ilike '%3%' will benefit from indexes based off of pg_trgm because they can't use traditional btree indexes.

Edit: @Abelisto's query in the comments is better because it should be more performant, especially if content can contain 1000s of elements:

```
select * from test 
where exists 
  (select 1 
   from jsonb_array_elements(content) jae(elems) 
   where elems ->> 0 = 'first 1' 
   and elems ->> 1 ilike '%3%'
  );
```

Comment: Using `exists` could be shorter and more convenient: `select * from test where exists (select 1 from jsonb_array_elements(content) jae(elems) where elems ->> 0 = 'first 1' and elems ->> 1 ilike '%3%')`

Comment: Thanks Abelisto, I like that as well.

Comment: @Jeremy I updated the question with expected data sizes. Can you include an example of creating the right index for the second list element (the one queried with `ILIKE`)?

Comment: @Abelisto "shorter" as in faster? Convenience is not a concern here. Correctness and performance is.

Comment: @user124114 It could be faster because it removes two operations from the query: `join` and `distinct`. But to get really good performance you need to normalize your data structure.

Comment: @Abelisto normalize in what sense?

Comment: @user124114 He means use single values per row instead of using jsonb.  If your data were in columns of (id, first_val, second_val) you could index first_val with a btree index and pretty easily add the trgm index to second_val.