# Postgres `gin_trgm_ops` index not being used

Tags: postgresql, performance, database-performance, query-performance, pg-trgm

I'm trying to [speed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56483600/composite-jsonb-array-query-in-postgres) some text matching in Postgres, using the `pg_trgm` extensions:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test3 (id bigint, key text, value text);

insert into test3 values (1, 'first 1', 'second 3');
insert into test3 values (2, 'first 1', 'second 2');
insert into test3 values (2, 'first 2', 'second 3');
insert into test3 values (3, 'first 1', 'second 2');
insert into test3 values (3, 'first 1', 'second 3');
insert into test3 values (4, 'first 2', 'second 3');
insert into test3 values (4, 'first 2', 'second 3');
insert into test3 values (4, 'first 1', 'second 2');
insert into test3 values (4, 'first 1', 'second 2');

-- repeat the above 1,000,000x times, to have more rows for benchmarking
insert into test3(id, key, value) select id, key, value from test3 cross join generate_series(1, 1000000);
```

Now I query this table with `ILIKE`:

```sql
select count(*) from test3 where key = 'first 1' and value ilike '%nd 3%';
Time: 918.265 ms
```

To see if indexing would speed this up, I added `pg_trgm` on both `key` and `value` columns:

```sql
CREATE extension if not exists pg_trgm;
CREATE INDEX test3_key_trgm_idx ON test3 USING gin (key gin_trgm_ops);
CREATE INDEX test3_value_trgm_idx ON test3 USING gin (value gin_trgm_ops);
```

But the query still takes the same time, and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` shows the indexes are not being used at all:

```sql
explain analyze select count(*) from test3 where key = 'first 1' and value ilike '%nd 3%';
                                                                 QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Finalize Aggregate  (cost=126905.14..126905.15 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1017.666..1017.667 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Gather  (cost=126904.93..126905.14 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=1017.505..1018.778 rows=3 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=125904.93..125904.94 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1010.862..1010.862 rows=1 loops=3)
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on test3  (cost=0.00..122427.06 rows=1391148 width=0) (actual time=0.041..973.550 rows=666667 loops=3)
                     Filter: ((value ~~* '%nd 3%'::text) AND (key = 'first 1'::text))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 2333336
 Planning Time: 0.266 ms
 Execution Time: 1018.814 ms

Time: 1049.413 ms (00:01.049)
```

Note the sequential scan. What gives?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Never mind, I found the issue.

The query planner was smarter than my toy test set; seeing as most rows match the query, it went for a sequential scan.

If I try with `ilike '%nd 0%'` instead, no rows match and EXPLAIN ANALYZE reports `Bitmap Index Scan on test3_value_trgm_idx` correctly.

So, normalizing the original JSONB in this manner works. But I'll also try to find and compare another way, using regular expressions over `TEXT`, to avoid having to create and maintain another table.